# На маленьких экранах не работает кнопка

Tags: html, css, button, modal

Более опытные разработчики, помогите, уже все испробовал.
Во время очередной верстки сайта у меня на маленьких экранах перестала работать кнопка.
При нажатии на "получить консультацию" должно появляться модальное окно с формой.
Не работает лишь на маленьких экранах.
Подскажите, в чем проблема?
Кидаю ссылку на сам сайт, т.к думаю, что через dt вам удобнее будет смотреть, что там такое.
http://ugryumovmm.ru/Gipsolit/
Как новенький в этом деле, открыт для любых замечаний, спасибо!

Comment: Ваш блок `class="main-content"` накрывает его своей невидимой частью. Или надо менять верстку, или добавить на эту кнопку `z-index: 2147483647;` — это максимально возможный индекс в браузере. В любом случае поставит эту кнопку на передний "слой". Хотя скорее всего можно было обойтись и просто `z-index: 1;` ))

Comment: Cпасибо большое!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.header {
замени  height на min-height
}
.main-content h1 {
padding 0; // у тебя 100px сверху которые налазят на кнопку.
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!)